# JPA: OneToMany relationship with multiple mappedBy attributes

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm having a problem to map a relationship between instances of one single entity. Let me give you the JPA entities first.

### Article entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "article")
public class Article {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "article", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<Keyword> keywords;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "article1", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Collection<RelatedArticles> relatedArticles;

    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    @Lob
    private String content;

    ...
}
```

### RelatedArticle entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "related_articles")
public class RelatedArticles {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "article1_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Article article1;

    @JoinColumn(name = "article2_id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Article article2;

    private Float weightedJaccardIndex;

    ...
}
```

### Further explanation

An article can be related to other articles which is realized by the `RelatedArticle` entity. The article can be referenced by `article1` or `article2`. That means the collection `relatedArticles` in `Article` should contain all instances of `RelatedArticle` where the ID either matches `article1` or `article2`.

### Question

How can I map a single collection of RelatedArticles in my `Article` entity where the origin `Article` is either article1 or article2?
Alternative solutions are welcome!

Comment: you can't. the mappedBy is simply to point to the reference in the related object where the FK is stored. If there are two optional FKs then that is not a standard relation so don't use the bidirectional aspect (mappedBy) and just have a 1-N and 2 N-1 UNIDIRECTIONAL relations.

Comment: Why would you even need it? Can't you just map the relationship to two separate sets and define an additional getter method, say `getAllArticles`, that returns the sum of the two sets?